# How can I migrate a PHP file version 5.6 to 7.2

Tags: php, migration, php-5.6, php-7.2

I bought a PHP software for the billing stuffs. It works fine on PHP 5.6 but in PHP 7.2 it does not work at all.
Error log:

> [06-Apr-2018 17:30:16 UTC] PHP Warning:  join(): Invalid arguments
>   passed in
>   /home/xxxxx/public_html/modules/addons/wmfatura/wmfaturabas.php on
>   line 559

**Line 559 on wmfaturabas.php:**

```
    Line 558: if ($cokmusteri != '') {
    Line 559:   $musteriler = join( ',', $cokmusteri );
    Line 560: }
```

What should I do? It should definitely work in PHP 7.2. I can't use PHP 5.6

Comment: @MadhurBhaiya is a core php function http://php.net/manual/en/function.join.php

Comment: what is the value of `$cokmusteri` it has to be an array

Comment: @IdontDownVote ohh well.. :-| ..learnt something new today

Comment: @Baran Do this on your line no 559 - `$musteriler = join( ',', (array)$cokmusteri );`

Comment: or (even better) find where the value is set and fix it

Comment: I agree with @IdontDownVote I think the real problem has occurred before this point in your code, where `$cokmusteri` was set. There are various differences between your two PHP versions that could cause this, but the fact that you're getting the error on that line just means that's where the problem has revealed itself. You need to trace back from that point and find out why `$cokmusteri` is not an array.

Comment: A more useful check for this condition `if($cokmusteri != ''){` is `if(is_array($cokmusteri)){`  That will make the error go away, however it as others noted it may not fix your issues.